# Finding belongs to entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model which has_one profile.

How can I find the user via the profile? For example is there a way in which I can find the user by checking all the profiles for the correct user_id column entry?

Comment: `profile.user`. Have you gone through a Rails tutorial (i.e. [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html))?

Answer (score 0):

The inverse relationship, if defined, will help:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So `profile.user` will fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

You should really read the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association).

To answer your question it's simple

`profile.user`

or

`user.profile`

Depending on what you want.